# Dataframe apply function with series as arguement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, apply

I want to apply a function *scipy.stats.percentileofscore()* to the rows of a dataframe using a series from the same / other dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(50, 25, size=(3, 10)).astype(int)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df['SCORE'] = [20,40,60]
```

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 24 | 39 | -3 | 32 | -26 | 61 | 88 | 36 | 32 | 59 | 20 |
| 1 | 26 | 63 | 17 | 55 | 79 | 3 | 108 | 73 | 73 | 92 | 40 |
| 2 | 38 | 67 | 82 | 53 | 40 | 61 | 39 | 32 | 59 | 78 | 60 |

Applying stats.percentileofscore() with static "score = 50" is straight forward

```
df['PCT OF SCORE'] = df.iloc[:,0:10].apply(stats.percentileofscore, score = 50, axis=1)
```

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | SCORE | PCT OF SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 24 | 39 | -3 | 32 | -26 | 61 | 88 | 36 | 32 | 59 | 20 | 70.0 |
| 1 | 26 | 63 | 17 | 55 | 79 | 3 | 108 | 73 | 73 | 92 | 40 | 30.0 |
| 2 | 38 | 67 | 82 | 53 | 40 | 61 | 39 | 32 | 59 | 78 | 60 | 40.0 |

However I want to use the df['SCORE'] series to set the "score" argument

```
df['PCT OF SCORE'] = df.iloc[:,0:20].apply(stats.percentileofscore, score = df['SCORE'], axis=1)
```

But this throws a ValueError

Ultimately I would like to keep the same code structure and just fix the syntax of "score" argument.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`score` of [`stats.percentileofscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html) should be array like, you can convert Series to list

```py
df['PCT OF SCORE'] = df.iloc[:,0:20].apply(stats.percentileofscore, score = df['SCORE'].tolist(), axis=1)
```

Also array like `score` is a new feature for [1.9.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.9.0.html)

> - [#13572](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/13572): ENH: n-D and nan_policy support for scipy.stats.percentileofscore

You need use upgrade scipy to newest with `pip3 install scipy --upgrade` or other package management tools.